# Day-to-day word for "corresponding" in this context

Tags: word-request

**Integers** are:

> All the *natural numbers,* their negative **corresponding** numbers and zero.

The word **corresponding** doesn't seem suitable for a child.

How a native speaker would say this to a child?

Is the word **respective** can also be used to mean the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Depends how old the "child" is. I would have understood corresponding when I was about 7 I think.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey but I wonder if you would give me a basic explanation for the word as the definitions vary from dictionary to dictionary.

Comment: You could just define them as all "whole" numbers. That's also supported by the etymology of the word *integer* (~ "intact"). Let's also not forget that natural numbers in some countries (namely France, I believe) include 0.

Answer (score 1):

While it’s not a synonym for *corresponding* overall, in this context, you can use the word *opposite*:

> All the natural numbers, their opposite, negative numbers and zero.

For example, as in this [explanation of negative](https://science.jrank.org/pages/4579/Negative.html):

> When negative is an adjective applied to a number or integer, the reference is to the opposite of a positive number. As a noun, negative is the opposite of any given number.

*Opposite* is a word that children learn extremely early in life (certainly before they’re ready to learn about negative numbers). It’s common for young children (at least as young as 3 years old) to have a [book of opposites](https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Books-Childrens-Opposites/zgbs/books/2766), many of which have the word on the front cover.

Answer (score 0):

> "Integers are all the natural numbers, their matching negative
>   numbers, and zero."

The word "respective" can be used interchangeably, but not quite suitable for a child either.

A native speaker would use the word "Matching".